# ROS Fuerte/Groovy install from source on ARM/Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: robotic-arm, pcl, ros-fuerte, odroid, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to install either Fuerte or Groovy from source on an ARM based processor.  For those interested, the board is the ODroid-U2.  There are various resources that I have used for assistance on the matter in regards to those who have attempted an install on pandaboards and raspberry pi.  If interested, they are given throughout.  I will mainly focus on my path in trying Fuerte, but if anyone has had it working with Groovy, I will go that route.

I haven't had a direct issue following [Fuerte+From_Source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) to install Fuerte.  I have made the directories and gotten to the point where I perform the "rosdep install -ay" command, but I receive warnings similar to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/40131/definition-for-ros-packages-on-debian-squeeze/).

Specifically, the error pertains to the fact that PCL cannot be found.  If you attempt to do a "rosmake -a", you also get an error related to [this](http://www.pcl-users.org/Trouble-installing-PCL-on-ARM-processor-with-ROS-td4025404.html).

I know this error is due to the fact that there isn't an ARM compatible version of ros-pcl, so I need to have the ability to compile it from source.  This is where my primary problem is.  I am not sure of how to do this.  I know of the resource for [pcl](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl), but I am not sure of the correct way to compile it and include it into ROS.  I am not too worried about the version of PCL at this time.

I have also attempted to do the same thing with Groovy.  I know there is an ARM based version of ROS to get started with Groovy, but it still does not include PCL.  In either case, I have not been able to find a good source for a method of building PCL and would appreciate any help on the matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63869/ros-fuerte/groovy-install-from-source-on-arm/ubuntu-12.04/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2013-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would start with the precompiled Groovy debs and then try to compile PCL and anything else you need on top of the deb-based install; you'll save yourself some time getting the base system set up.

I think PCL compiles fairly well on ARM, but you'll probably want to adjust the build flags. In particular, flags that enable SSE optimizations will fail because ARM doesn't have SSE, and you'll want to turn the number of parallel builds down to 1, because PCL tends to use a lot of memory when compiling.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-29**:
to increase your swap you can also format an USB drive as a swap device and use it for faster compilation. This way the swap is not written to the SD card

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-05-30**:
ahendrix, I completely agree and have gone this route. I have installed Groovy from the current deb-based install described on the ROS site. It is the installing PCL part that I am lost on. I am not sure of which PCL to get. I downloaded a few and they did compile correctly, but ROS never found it.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-30**:
remove all other pcl installs and try sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pcl

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-05-30**:
kalectro, thanks, but I have seen that solution many places.  It will not work.  I have not found a source that has an ARM compiled version of ros-groovy-pcl.  I may have been missing something, but that didn't work for me.  Only worked when compiling from source on X86/X64 based computer.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-30**:
sorry... I thought there was a pcl binary available. If not, you can compile it from source using the version in my repo https://github.com/kalectro/pcl_groovy.git Use the rasPi branch

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-05-30**:
kalectro, that is the root of my problem.  When I grab the source, where should I compile it to.  Should I place it in the root of /opt, place in either the share/stacks locations within ROS, or place it in my workspace.  I know it shouldn't matter, but it wasn't working for me when I tried.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-30**:
clone the code into the src folder of your catkin environment. You can also create a new catkin workspace just for this purpose. Then compile the code using catkin_make_isolated --install

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-05-30**:
I attempted to build this but got the following error http://pastebin.com/DCbrCr2n. I attempted using my primary workspace as it was new and I am not sure how to setup multiple workspaces in groovy yet (was able to in Fuerte).  Any ideas.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-31**:
catkin_make_install --install -j1

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-05-31**:
That still didn't work, however, I found what the problem was. Through some sources talking about how to change the CMake file, they all mention a setting armv6. When changing that to my setup (armv7) it worked on both the ROS PCL code and your modified CMake file.

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-06-01**:
sorry I forgot you were working on the Odroid... using the branch for the raspberry pi is not really a good idea then because it uses optimizations for its architecture. It should however work with the master branch

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-06-01**:
You are right.  I figured that out through a few different avenues.  I finally got it to compile, however, now I am having an issue with YAML, which I posted elsewhere.  I will edit this soon with a combined solution between your and my discussion.  Thanks very much for the help.

**Comment by [uwlau](https://answers.ros.org/users/4031/uwlau/) on 2013-06-13**:
hey @orion. i do have the same problem with compiling PCL for my PandaBoardES. Do you have your "combined solution" yet?

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2013-07-04**:
It has not been tested yet, but there are ARM binaries for PCL, built for the RPi. You may want to check this repository: http://64.91.227.57/repos/rospbian/